# A intersection (A union B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$. I'm stuck on the last part of my proof, not sure how to show next:

$$x \in A \cap (A \cup B)$$
$$\iff x \in A \;\;\text{and}\;\; x \in A \cup B$$
$$\iff x \in A \;\;\text{and}\;\; (\text{either}\;\; x \in A \;\;\text{or}\;\; x \in B).$$

Comment: Would you use a truth table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statements $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$ and $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$ are known as *absorption laws*.

When the proof is not clear using the equivalence "if and only if", one can try proving the direct first and later the converse, or viceversa.

*Proof.* $(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose $x \in A \cap (A \cup B)$. Then we have simultaneously $x \in A$ and $x \in A \cup B$, by Definition 2. Thus $x \in A$ as desired.

$(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose $x \in A$. By Definition 1, we have $x \in A \cup B$. Thus, we have $x \in A$ (by hypothesis) "**and**" $x \in A \cup B$. Hence, by Definition 2, $x \in A \cap (A \cup B)$ as desired.

> *Definition 1* (Union)*.* $x \in A \cup B \;\iff\; (x \in A \;\;\text{or}\;\; x \in B)$.
>
> *Definition 2* (Intersection)*.* $x \in A \cap B \;\iff\; (x \in A \;\;\text{and}\;\; x \in B)$.

If you want to use the *if and only if* clause, you only need "to assembly" the two parts of the proof.

Remember:

- if $P$ is true, then $P \;\;\text{or}\;\; anything$ is true.
- if $P \;\;\text{and}\;\; Q$ is true, then $P$ is true.
- if $P \;\;\text{and}\;\; Q$ is true, then $Q$ is true.

Answer (score 4):

From $x \in A$ and ($x \in A$ or $x \in B$), you can conclude that $x \in A$, or the first clause is false and the whole statement is false. You are already there.

Answer (score 3):

$A\subseteq A\cup B\,$ so $A\subseteq A\cap(A\cup B)\;$, and $\;A\cap(A\cup B)\subseteq A\;$
so $\;A=A\cap(A\cup B)$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $A$ is always a subset of $A\cup B$. And a subset's intersection with the  set containing it always results in the subset only.