# Derive the set identity $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Derive the set identity of:  $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$

Really need help.
I do not know how to reach end result. 
Please assist.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965347/a-intersection-a-union-b).