# Prove by double inclusion the set identity $A\cap(A\cup B) = A$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove by double inclusion the set identity $A\cap(A\cup B) = A$

please help with this am stuck with these identities on the set A and B

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965347/a-intersection-a-union-b)

Answer (score 3):

$A\cap (A\cup B)\subseteq A$:

Let $x\in A\cap (A\cup B)$. Then $x\in A$ (and $x\in A \cup B$), by definition of intersection.

---

$A\subseteq A\cap (A\cup B)$:

Let $x\in A$. Then $x\in A\cup B$ (by definition of union). Thus $x\in A\cap (A\cup B)$, by the definition of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

$A \cap(A \cup B)=(A \cup \varnothing)\cap (A \cup B)=A \cup(B \cap \varnothing)=A \cup\varnothing=A$